# Magento 1.8.1.0 Google Checkout missing - comparing to 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, google-checkout

I got errors in logs related to Google Checkout, I found that Magento 1.8.1.0 doesn't have Google Checkout in configuration, also file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googlecheckout.xml is missing from ZIP installation files. Comparing to 1.8.0.0 they have removed it or they broken it. I don't know - but Gomage Lightcheckout is triggering errors trying to load Google Checkout block.

How to fix it ? I dont; plan to use google checkout - but like to avoid errors in Gomage Lightcheckout related to Google Shopping Cart ? should I re-copy app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googlecheckout.xml from Magento 1.8.0.0. to 1.8.1.0 ?
I don;t know because changelogs shows that they were fixing some Google Checkout issues

Thanks for help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento 1.8.1 **removes** Google Checkout due to Google announcing the product's **end of life** in November of 2013.

Any extensions depending on the presence of Google Checkout modules or layout in Magento may prevent your upgrade to 1.8.1. I recommend in the time-being that you either contact the vendors of those modules or you forego the upgrade. Modifying the modules directly would either void your support contracts with them or cause yourself other issues.

To 'bring forward' the Google Checkout module from 1.8.0 to 1.8.1 little more is required than to copy the app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout module, layout, adminhtml- and frontend- theme files; though I **do not recommend** you to do this.