# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object for class Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Shipping

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods, google-checkout

When I click the `Add to cart` button I'm getting the following error `"Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in ../app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php"`

This is the function that throws it:

```
   public function getCarrierByCode($carrierCode, $storeId = null)
    {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/'.$this->_availabilityConfigField, $storeId)) {
            return false;
        }
        $className = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/model', $storeId);
        if (!$className) {
            return false;
        }
        $obj = Mage::getModel($className);
        if ($storeId) {
            $obj->setStore($storeId);
        }
        return $obj;
    }
```

This code in particular:

```
$obj = Mage::getModel($className);
if ($storeId) {
    $obj->setStore($storeId);
}
```

I have printed out the `$obj` and I'm getting the following object:

```
Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Shipping Object
(
    [_code:protected] => googlecheckout
    [_rates:protected] => 
    [_numBoxes:protected] => 1
    [_freeMethod:protected] => free_method
    [_isFixed:protected] => 
    [_customizableContainerTypes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_debugReplacePrivateDataKeys:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

This `Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Shipping` class is present, it's in the right location.

I can see that the functions loads the `$className` in the following manner:

```
$className = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/model', $storeId);
```

and while for the Fedex, UPS etc. methods I see entries in the `core_config_data` table like this `carriers/fedex/something`, for the Google Checkout I do not, but I see the following instead: `google/checkout_shipping_carrier/active` and many others that do not follow the `carriers/carrierCode` pattern.

Anyway, does someone know why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can probably safely disable `Mage_GoogleCheckout` in `System -> Config -> Advanced -> Advanced` because per this post, Google Checkout officially stopped in November 2013 and Magento dropped support for it:

[Magento 1.8.1.0 Google Checkout missing - comparing to 1.8.0.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14773/magento-1-8-1-0-google-checkout-missing-comparing-to-1-8-0-0)

Comment: Ok, I've disabled `Mage_GoogleCheckout` and the error in `Sales -> Google API` is gone, but the error on the frontend when adding to cart is still there. Do you think it's wise to remove the DB entries for GoogleCheckout?

Comment: Removing the database entries would probably just lead to a different error.  Try renaming the layout file `googlecheckout.xml` to remove it for your theme and see if that fixes your front-end error.

Comment: Did not help at all

Answer (score 0):

Google checkout no longer exists but should you need the module working for some reason my guess is that the contents of `$className` is not valid so `getModel()` is not returning an object.

Comment: Ok, I've disabled `Mage_GoogleCheckout` and the error in `Sales -> Google API` is gone, but the error on the frontend when adding to cart is still there. Do you think it's wise to remove the DB entries for GoogleCheckout?

Comment: How have you disabled `Mage_GoogleCheckout`?

Comment: By setting this

`<Mage_GoogleCheckout>
            <active>false</active>`

in Mage_All.xml

Comment: Cleared at least the config cache?

Comment: Yeah, I've emptied the var/cache directory manually. No dice :/